# TypeError: global.registerWebpackModules is not a function

Tags: android, webpack, nativescript, nativescript-cli

I'm trying to build and run NativeScript project HelloWorld with following command

```
$ tns run android --bundle
```

Project successfully built. But it crash with following errors https://gist.githubusercontent.com/webleaf/c12e71ea73a313d7df61545b5652c0ce/raw/b2d8ad7ada81569cc0c42ea5c82eb6d0c88b450c/gistfile1.txt

Errors disappear (and looks like helloworld app run ok), if I delete following strings from app/vendor.js

```
global.registerWebpackModules(appCssContext);
application.loadAppCss();
```

...because this methods unresolved.

Without `--bundle` opt all build ok and run ok.
Don't know how to resolve this methods, when run with `--bundle` opt (using webpack)

Comment: Did you add those lines? Usually they reside inside `vendor.ts` which is used only when using `--bundle`.

Comment: The problem I'm talking about appears only with `--bundle`. And those lines are there by default.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem was resolved by update dependencies of tutorial template package.js (updating version of tns-core-modules).